# Error while Querying a many-to-many relationship in Grails

Tags: grails

```
class Address {
    static hasMany = [addressGroups: AddressGroup]
    ...
}

class AddressGroup {
    static belongsTo = Address
    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

    String notation;
    ...
}
```

I try to fetch all Addresses  for a given AddressGroup.

My code:

```
def params = [max: 10]
def addressGroup = AddressGroup.findByNotation("asdf")
def addresses = Address.findAllByAddressGroups(addressGroup, params)
```

The error message: **No value specified for parameter 2**

The logged SQL statement:

```
select ... from ADDRESSES this_ where this_.id=10 order by this_.id asc limit ** NOT SPECIFIED **
```

... which is completly wrong.

Any ideas?

I could fetch the Addresses by using addressGroup.addresses (and that works!), but I want to display it in a table with pagination so i need to max / offset params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... I tried using the GORM extension, but after looking at it a bit closer I saw it has not what i need.

I endet up using the Criteria API:

```
def c = Address.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
   if(params.addressGroup) {
      addressGroups {
         eq('id', params.addressGroup)
      }
   }

   maxResults(params.max)
   order(params.sort, params.order)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the dynamic finders take the pagination parameters you need.

Check out [GORM Labs Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gorm-labs), which introduces some extensions to GORM. Section "Paginated HasMany Properties" shows you how to do what you are looking for.